# How to set maximum limit of lines used inside a Python function using Pylint?

Tags: python-3.x, pylint, pylintrc

**Example:**

```
def exmaple_function():
            a = 1
            b = 2
            c = 3
            d = a * b + c
            print(d)
```

As you can see above function constitutes of 6 lines from start of **(def)** to end of **(print(d))**.

Is there a **way to set limit in Pylint Config-file** of the lines used inside python function?
**example: max-lines-of-function=4 using Pylint with configuration file**.

Answer (score 2):

This is the `too-many-statements` warnings, the default value is 50 but you can change it to something else with a pylintrc configuration:

```
[DESIGN]
# Maximum number of statements in function / method body
max-statements=50
```

Comment: max-statements refers only to the number if else statments used inside a method/function, not exactly the number of line counts inside the function/method.

Comment: And i am not refering to that warning, Instead is there a way to set warning saying that your function should not exceed to the limit sepcified for number of lines used inside the function.

Comment: ``max-statements`` is exactly the option you're asking for, if you set the value to 5 it will raise a warning ``too-many-statements`` for the 6 lines function in your question. [Source](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/pull/4589/).

Comment: If you are working on an existing pylintrc file and `max-statements` doesn't seem to work, check if it appears under `disable=`. Watch out for indirect deactivation, e.g. through `disable=R` which disables all `[DESIGN]` checks.